# for panda %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, pandas, winapi

I'm a python beginner and I used jupyter notebook. Everything was fine until today and when I tried to import pandas this morning as usual, it reported error like this '[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application'.

I looked into some answers for former questions but they didn't make sense to me. My anaconda is 64bit and pandas is also 64bit. Why is the error? What should I do?

```
import pandas as pd
```

And I get error :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-2f05c4dd09d8> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     11 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     12     try:
---> 13         __import__(dependency)
     14     except ImportError as e:
     15         missing_dependencies.append(dependency)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
--> 142     from . import core
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     21             # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     22             # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 23             WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     24             DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     25     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

~\Downloads\Anaconda\anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    354 
    355         if handle is None:
--> 356             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    357         else:
    358             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: `Win32` in the message has nothing to do with 64-bit versus 32-bit. If you ask your interpreter to show you `sys.platform` it will say `'win32'` even on a 64-bit machine. The message is telling you it is trying to load a DLL that it can't find.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! But can you tell me what I can do to fix this problem? I have already installed pandas why can't my interpreter find it ? Should I fix the path in jupyter notebook? It was all good before and suddenly crashed today, I don't understand what happened.

Comment: @Boar Actually that message is what you get whe 32 bit process attempts to load 64 bit DLL and vice versa. Also that second comment is nonsense.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But how can I fix it?

Comment: Hard to say. Could be caused by many things. What changed recently?